# How to test "App Update" in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, windows-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I want to test the use case in which a user has version 1.0 of my app and the phone notifies that a **new version** of the app is available.

Is there a way to test this scenario using **Visual Studio**?

How can i update an existing App in my phone to see how it works?
Mainly, i want to test that old data is still accesible after the update.

Answer (score 2):

Use this tools for test apdate your app.
[Application Deployment tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn632395.aspx)

It is suitable and if you use the update task in your application.

Comment: Is there a way to update an app from the Phone? I deploy my appxupload in the phone. But then how do i tell it to update manually?

Comment: I think that there is no way to test the update. And do not understand why you need exactly your scenario. Application Deployment tool simulates the application update as it passes in and out of the store and when you manually install from SD card.

The update occurs equally from any source.
If you tested the update through Application Deployment tool then you can be sure that after the publication of the application in the store update will be successful in any possible way for the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command line interface of the **Application Deployment tool** ([full documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn632395.aspx)) to easily simulate an app update:

1. Open admin command prompt.
2. Navigate to the directory for the Application Deployment tool: `cd "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Tools\AppDeploy"`
3. Find the index of the device or emulator you're using for testing: `AppDeployCmd.exe /EnumerateDevices`
4. Install the old app: `AppDeployCmd.exe /installlaunch "C:\Old.xap" /targetdevice:12` where `C:\Old.xap` is the path to the old app, and `12` is the device/emulator index found in the previous step.
5. Update to the new app: `AppDeployCmd.exe /updatelaunch "C:\New.xap" /targetdevice:12` where `C:\New.xap` is the path to the old app, and `12` is the device/emulator index found in step 3.

Answer (score 0):

How are you checking if a new version is available? Do you check from the Store, or query your own web service? In former case, you can use publish a beta app, install in your device and then publish an update to that beta (You'll need developer account for that). The latter case is pretty straightforward.

For your second question, I agree with @user2784555. The deployment tool is what you need.

Comment: I'm not checking for updates. The phone should automatically check if the app needs to be updated. Another way, is to install an older version of the app and go to the Store, if the store offers you the UPDATE option instead INSTALL option, you could test the update. But i wasn't able to deploy a appx package in the device associated with the store. It always says INSTALL in the store app, it does not recognize it is the same App.

Comment: Are you deploying the OLDER version through deployment tool? In that case it won't work. You need to install it via Store. I'd suggest using the Beta store for this purpose, as it will not go through certification process and hence ideal for such tests.

Comment: Yes i am installing the Older version of the app..Is there a Beta store?

Comment: Yes. You indicate your app as Beta during submission. It gets published within 2 hours. Only the beta testers that you specify can download it. It is not discoverable by others. Here are the details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj215598(v=vs.105).aspx